# How to draw driving route from current location to destination by google map api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to draw a driving line from my current location to destination including all the waypoints

```
@Override
public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
    Log.d("Status", "Success");
    Log.d("Direction", "" + direction);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(origin));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destination));
    if (waypoints != null){
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.size(); i++){
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(waypoints.get(i)));
        }
    }

    ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = direction.getRouteList().get(0).getLegList().get(0).getDirectionPoint();
    mMap.addPolyline(DirectionConverter.createPolyline(this, directionPositionList, 5, Color.BLUE));

    Log.d("Status", "Success 2");
    showRoute.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: For including specific waypoints, look at the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints

Comment: Thanks all ready done it, working.